# angular custom directive to trim spaces works but validation fails

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, trim, angular-directive

In my ionic3 angular application I need to trim the spaces from an email input field while the user is typing. To do so I created a Directive like this:

```
    @Directive({
  selector: '[no-space]',
  host: {
    "(input)": 'onInputChange($event)'
  }
})
export class NoSpaceDirective{
  onInputChange($event){
    $event.target.value = $event.target.value.trim();
  }
}
```

the directive works, however the validation does not behave correctly: the validation is set to not allow spaces in the value; when I type a space it is trimmed by the directive but the validation fails as if the space is not visible but still there.

Comment: To my knowledge, validation checks are only performed on an input change event. Since you are directly changing the value, it would not re-validate. I also don't understand why you need to continuously trim spaces *and* validate for spaces. Can't you just trim the value once they submit the form?

Comment: Validation of what? Is this a reactive form?

Comment: Yes it is a reactive form. My problem is that my submit button is enabled when the form is valid. So I can't submit (and execute the trim before submit) if the email field is not valid. In this way the user is forced to put an email without spaces but my goal is to trim the spaces automatically because on devices with the autocompletion sometimes the space is added without the user knowing it and this generates confusion.

Answer (score 0):

To optimized solution to your problem is to prevent user to type space and we can achieve that using the following code.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[no-space]',
  host: {
    "(input)": 'onInputChange($event)'
  }
})
export class NoSpaceDirective{
  if ($event.key === ' ' || $event.key === 'Spacebar') {
    // ' ' is standard, 'Spacebar' was used by IE9 and Firefox < 37
    return false; //preventing type space character
    console.log('Space pressed')
  } else {
      return true; 
}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: thanks for the interest to my problem. This should fix part of the problem: if the user select an email from an autocomplete function instead of typing it, spaces may be pasted in the input .